# Compare two data sets in different sheet and print difference in other sheet using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two data sets in two different sheet 
Sheet1 is my Orginal ref and sheet2 is for comparison.
sheet2 data should get compared by Sheet1 and print entire mismatched row of sheet2
 and highlight the cells which has mismatch data and this difference should be printed with column header in other
specified Sheet and in specified range

Also mismatch cell count should be updated in any sheet3 specified range cell

Below is the tried code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub CompareDataSet()
Call compareSheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
End Sub
Sub compareSheets(Sheet1 As String, Sheet2 As String)
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CellMisMatch As Integer
For Each Cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).UsedRange
If Not Cell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2).Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).Value Then
Let Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column) = Cell
Cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
CellMisMatch = CellMisMatch + 1
End If
Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Value = CellMisMatch
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that will compare sheet1 and sheet2(corresponding cells ) and according wite the correct value or Mismatch based upon the result into sheet3. Sheet1 and sheet2 wil have same number of rows and columns and the headers be same so you can keep them as it is in sheet3. Hope it helps.

```
Sub Compare()

'Clearing the contents of the third sheet for the fresh comparison

usedCoulms = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Columns.Count
usedRows = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To usedRows
For j = 1 To usedCoulms
   Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
   Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Next
Next

'Coulmn count of first sheet
ColumnCount = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
'row count of first sheet
RowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To RowCount
For j = 1 To ColumnCount
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value <> Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value Then    'Comparing if values are not equal
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, j).Value 'Copying the Header of the Mismatched Cell
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Value = CStr("MisMatch")   'If mismatch setting set value as MisMatch
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535     'Highlighting with Yellow color

    Else
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value
        'If values are same copy the first sheets value if dont want to copy can skip this
    End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: dude Manish, your comment is little rude to me.
How can you think that i got this question with out trying itself.this is tiny piece of my work.

Here is code which i tried little bit..but not in high level.
Sry if my explanation is harsh.

Comment: sorry if i sound rude to you. But when you are asking a question you are supposed to tell what you have tried and give some code so that the viewers can help you better. and in your question there was no mention of any code or what you tried. and your last words "Is it possible " they show as if your are asking without trying.

Comment: Hey i have updated the answer hope it helps. feel free to ask me for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks dude, it works great.. but one query
1.Instead of using entire sheet which is used...how can we do compare only with specific range( where exactly data/table is located in sheet1 and sheet2) and print this in other sheet3 in customized range. bcs some other stuff which are not require for compare is also getting print in sheet3 and it is getting override
2. To print mismatch count, we can use =COUNTIF(range i will specify range here,"MisMatch") is this gud enough or any other alternative method is exists..once again thanks for spending u r valuable time

Comment: =COUNTIF(A2:A7,"Mismatch") this way you can count the no of mismatches just adjust the range. And for comparing the specified range you can change the initial value of loop counters to start from the particular row and cell and on until the value you require then it will compare the specified range only. And if the answer was helpful you can mark it as a answer.

Comment: Hey @nani if the answer really helped you you can mark it as an accepted answer or rate the answer by upvoting.